# .htaccess block certain website

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am wondering if it possible to a site-wide block of a certain website, for example - block flickr.com  which would include 'img' src's and css? As in blocking users from hotlinking to Flickr

If so how would I configure this in an htaccess

Thank you,

Comment: That's rudimentary. Inside your images directory, include an .htaccess with `Order deny,allow Deny from example.com`

Comment: Are you talking about other sites hotlinking from your site? Or don't you want users on your site to link to other sites? Please expand your question.

Comment: The later, users not hot linking Flickr. So to block all requests to that domain

Comment: You can't do that in .htaccess. You'd need to do it in your PHP code that processes the user-submitted content prior to displaying it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.+\.)?mysite\.com/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteRule .*\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png)$ http://i.imgur.com/qX4w7.gif [L]
```

[Stop Hotlinking](http://altlab.com/htaccess_tutorial.html)