# Allow and block sites with HTTP_REFERER

Tags: php, redirect, if-statement

i must allow some sub-sites to link my pages, but i dont want to allow the main site to do that.

the main site is www.mainsite.com, and this site mustnt link my pages, but the sub-site www.mainsite.com/subsite must be allowed to link the pages, like all the others sites on the web. 
in simple terms i want to block the sites that rip my content from my site without asking permissions or sites that abuse of my bandwidth. I tried to do this, but the code dont work, can someone help me?

CODE:

```
<?php
$ref=$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

if (strpos($ref,'http://randomsite/allowedsite1')===0 || strpos($ref,'http://randomsite/allowedsite2')===0){} //If the referer comes from an allowed site, it must show the HTML below
if (strpos($ref,'http://randomsite/')===0 || strpos($ref,'http://anotherblockedrandomsite/')===0){
header('location: http://mycoolsite/nohotlink.png'); //if the referer comes from an blocked site, it redirects to an troll png
exit();
}
?>

<html>
My Password
</html>
```

Comment: Generally referer is not a secure thing. Browsers can forge it too easily.

Comment: You can't control the contents on other websites. They can link to any site they want -- you can't control it. Is that what you're asking? If not, please update the question and make it clear.

Comment: Otherwise an if {} else {} structure seems to be more safe. If the blocked sites name changes then it the changed name will be allowed by default.

Comment: HTTP_REFERER is not sent by all clients, this is not a workable solution for access control

Answer (score 0):

use `=== true` or `=== false` instead of `0`. `0` can be interpreted as `INT`

On another note, contact the other sites and tell them to remove your content. it's the only way to do this and there's pretty much nothing you can do about it.

Comment: dont work, it works from randomsite/allowedsite1 but also from randomsite/. randomsite/ must be blocked...

Comment: Then use your htaccess to set a blocked list.

Comment: I would suggest reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229736/htaccess-block-certain-website